# Why playwright isn't modifying request body?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I need to modify the request body that is sent by the browser, i do it like this:

```py
async def handle_uri_route(route: Route):
    response = await route.fetch()
    response_json = await response.json()

    reg_notification_uri = response_json['confirmUri']
    await page.route(reg_notification_uri, modify_notification_uri)

    await route.continue_()

async def modify_notification_uri(route: Route):
    post_data = route.request.post_data_json
    post_data['notificationUi'] = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'

    await route.continue_(post_data=urlencode(post_data))
    pprint(route.request.post_data_json)

await page.route(re.compile(r'api\/common\/v1\/register_notification_uri\?'), handle_uri_route)
```

`pprint` displays the changed data, but if i open the devtools, then i see that the request hasn't really changed.
What am I doing wrong?